# IntelliJ can't find stepdefinition when using cucumber-java8

Tags: kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm trying to use Cucumber with java8 for the first time. My Ide is IntelliJ.

When I'm using the build-in Step-Generator from IntelliJ I can create the steps-skeleton, but all Steps are marked as not implementen... when I run the tests the steps will be found.

Do I have a wrong configuration? Is it a IDE-Bug?

[screenshot from IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nmNA.png)

I also tried to move the step-definitions in different directories. When I generate the steps with java (without 8) code will be generated and steps can be clicked in Ide.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you added shows Kotlin code. Afaik there was an issue with Kotlin step defs not being recognized by IntelliJ. Not sure whether that issue has been resolved yet. You might try upgrading your Cucumber for Java plugin, and/or check Jetbrains YouTrack to see if the issue was already resolved.

Comment: [Bug is already accepted by JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203245)